# WinError 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it [InfluxDB with Flask]

Tags: python, windows, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, influxdb

Okay, so I'm trying to set up influxdb for flask.
Since there is a [library](https://github.com/btashton/flask-influxdb) already that does this, I tried to give it a go.
I went over the example directory that the README referenced, so this is what I ended up with:

```
from flask_influxdb import InfluxDB
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'applesandpears'
influx_db = InfluxDB(app=app)


@app.route('/newdb/<dbname>')
def newdb(dbname):
    dbcon = influx_db.connection
    dbcon.create_database(dbname)
    return ''


@app.route('/write/<dbname>')
def write(dbname):
    data_measurement = 'testseries'
    data_tags = ['time', 'value_1', 'value_2', 'value_3']

    dbcon = influx_db.connection
    dbcon.switch_database(database=dbname)
    dbcon.write_points([
        {
            "fields": {
                'value_1': 0.5,
                'value_2': 1,
                'value_3': 1.8858
            },
            "tags": {
                'tag_1': 'tag_string',
                'tag_2': 'tag_string'
            },
            "measurement": "testseries"
        }
    ])
    tabledata = dbcon.query('SELECT {0} from {1}'.format(', '.join(data_tags), data_measurement))

    data_points = []
    for measurement, tags in tabledata.keys():
        for p in tabledata.get_points(measurement=measurement, tags=tags):
            data_points.append(p)

    return render_template('table.html',
                           measurement=data_measurement,
                           columns=data_tags,
                           points=data_points)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

When I try the following query `http://localhost:5000/newdb/testdb`, I get the following error:

`requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8086): Max retries exceeded with url: /query?q=CREATE+DATABASE+%22testdb%22 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000013DF2AB7E10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',))`

The wrapper code for creating the database can be found [here](https://github.com/btashton/flask-influxdb/blob/master/flask_influxdb.py)

Now, I understand that this is not influx-db specific error, rather Windows error. I went over other articles and tried disabling the firewall, but that doesn't seem to work.  I also tried running cmd as administrator, but again, nothing happened.

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Is your influxdb running? can you use influx in command-line and create a database? Is chronograph connecting to your database successfully? If db is working fine, I suggest using Pinform (https://github.com/sinarezaei/pinform) or Python-InfluxDB (https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-python) and checking if they result in similar error, but I believe it's more of a connection issue

Answer (score 0):

> This could be because of proxy. You need to specify proxy setting at
>   entry point of your code or project.

```
import os #for proxy

proxy = 'http://10.XX.XX.XX:8X8X' #your own proxy 'http://<user>:<pass>@<proxy>:<port>'

os.environ['http_proxy'] = proxy 
os.environ['HTTP_PROXY'] = proxy
os.environ['https_proxy'] = proxy
os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY'] = proxy
#rest of code .....
```